# Bind not required (empty) parameter into a PDO query

Tags: php, pdo

I have created a "Feedback" section on a website. In this section, I've included a text field for comments and star rating system. The rating input is not required (people are not forced to leave rates) and is used to create a `$_POST['rating']` integer variable (1-5) which is binded into an insert PDO query:

```
$dbms->bindparam(':rating', $_POST['rating'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

This works well when `$_POST['rating']` variable is set, but when it's not I get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'rating' at row 1
```

Is there any way (i.e. a flag) to tell PDO to bind a parameter only if it's not empty and use MySQL default value instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(empty($_POST['rating'])) $_POST['rating'] = 0;
```

Somewhere before your bind. This will thus always give PDO an int value regardless of user action. If rating isn't set, the rating becomes 0.